# Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Form' not found in Laravel PHP Project - Form

Tags: php, forms, laravel, laravel-5, package

So I just installed the Form/Html package from Laravel Collective. Installed via Composer, added to providers, and added alias for both Form and Html, but I am still unable to access the class no matter what I try. I've tried the following:

```
use Form;

use Collective\Html\FormFacade;

\Form::select(...);
```

Nothing seems to be working. Is there anything I am missing? Also have run composer dumpautoload. Thanks!

Comment: Try this `use Collective\Html\FormFacade as Form`

Comment: Form is a facade, you don't need use the full namespace of the class. Try remove the use statements. After this call \Form::...

Comment: @Maraboc now it says the class does not exist. The package is definitely installed...

Comment: Why you want to call Form from the controller ??

Comment: I don't I want to call from the view but the same exception is being thrown in that instance. I'm trying it from the controller just for testing purposes

Comment: Got it. Ran php artsan config:cache. Thanks guys!